# Unix domain socket bind failed in windows

Tags: c++, boost, cross-platform, boost-asio, unix-socket

I'm running the following code in order to create listener to unix domain socket.
Under macOS this code is working fine, but in Windows it produces the following error from the tcp_acceptor command : `WSAEOPNOTSUPP`

Here's a minimal reproducible example :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio/local/stream_protocol.hpp>
constexpr char* kFileName = "file.sock";
using namespace std;
using namespace boost::asio;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    io_context my_io_context;
    ::_unlink(kFileName); // Remove previous binding.
    local::stream_protocol::endpoint server(kFileName);
    local::stream_protocol::acceptor acceptor(my_io_context, server);
    local::stream_protocol::socket socket(my_io_context);
    acceptor.accept(socket);
    return 0;
}
```

While debugging inside the boost library, i saw that the failure comes from the internal bind in the following code :

[image]

and this is the frame variables (it's clearly visible that sa_family = AF_UNIX (1):

[image]

I know that unix domain socket was introduced in windows10 few years ago, and i'm working with the latest version so it should be supported. Any idea what's wrong in my code?

EDIT : I've found out that in linux based machine I pass the following sockaddr to ::bind

````
(const boost::asio::detail::socket_addr_type) *addr = (sa_len = '\0', sa_family = '\x01', sa_data = "/tmp/server.sock")
(lldb) memory read addr
0x7ffeefbffa00: 00 01 2f 74 6d 70 2f 73 65 72 76 65 72 2e 73 6f  ../tmp/server.so
0x7ffeefbffa10: 63 6b 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ck..............```
````

and in windows i get a slightly different struct :

```
{sa_family=1 sa_data=0x000000fffd33f682 "C:\\temp\\UnixSo... }const sockaddr *
```

Notice that the `len` field is missing in the windows platform.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want such sockets on windows?

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis, I want to create a cross platform ipc service. Windows should support it (https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/af_unix-comes-to-windows/)

Comment: "should be supported" Did you check `sc query afunix`?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem., I get state running.

Comment: You are wasting time. Windows has file mapping which is the preferred IPC mechanism. No need to be cross platform for something you would not need to interoperate. Generally, Linux stuff that is presumably portable does not work well on windows and windows developers don't bother with such stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be the `SO_REUSEADDR` socket option, which ASIO by default sets. Setting this option itself succeeds, but causes the subsequent `bind` to fail.

Construct the acceptor with [`reuse_addr`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket_acceptor/basic_socket_acceptor/overload5.html) = `false`, then the binding should succeed:

```
  local::stream_protocol::acceptor acceptor(my_io_context, server, false);
```

Comment: Looks great. Btw, I couldn't find any official Microsoft documentation about this flag not support on Windows ... How did you figure it out ?

Comment: It comes with experience :-) When something that should work doesn't, try disabling unnecessary options.